# Query string argument of EXECUTE is null

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, psql

**EDIT**

It seems my issue is when this select statement returns null (which is the case I'm trying to handle - when it returns null, I want my new value to be -999). How can I go about doing this if it errors out whenever a null is found?

**ORIGINAL**

I have read every other SO post I could find regarding this error, but none of which seemed to address the root of my issue.

The error is pretty straightforward - one of my arguments within my EXECUTE statement is null. Great. However, I print out each of the values that make up my EXECUTE statement right before it gets called, and I can clearly see that none of the values are null.

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inform_icrm_prob_flow_query(tablename text, location_id int,
                                            product_date_str text, lead_time_start int,
                                            lead_time_end int, first_member_id int,
                                            last_member_id int, dest_file text)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  count int;
  product_date TIMESTAMPTZ;
  interval_lead_time_start text;
  interval_lead_time_end text;
  curr_value double precision;
  query text;
BEGIN
  product_date := product_date_str::TIMESTAMPTZ;
  count := first_member_id;
  curr_value := 0;

  interval_lead_time_start :=  ''''|| product_date ||'''::timestamptz +
                               interval '''||lead_time_start||' hours''';
  interval_lead_time_end :=  ''''|| product_date ||'''::timestamptz +
                             interval '''||lead_time_end||' hours'' -
                             interval ''6 hours''';

  --create our temporary table and populate it's date column
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_icrm_prob_flow AS 
             SELECT * FROM generate_series('||interval_lead_time_start || ',' || 
                                            interval_lead_time_end || ', ''6 hours'') 
                           AS date_valid';
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN count > last_member_id;
    IF NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT 'date_valid'
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name='temp_table_icrm_prob_flow'
        and column_name='value'||count||'') 
    THEN
      EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE temp_table_icrm_prob_flow ADD COLUMN value' || count 
               || ' double precision DEFAULT -999';
    END IF;

    raise notice 'tablename: %', tablename;
    raise notice 'location_id: %', location_id;
    raise notice 'product_date: %', product_date;
    raise notice 'count: %', count;

    query := 'SELECT value FROM '|| tablename ||' 
              INNER JOIN temp_table_icrm_prob_flow
              ON (temp_table_icrm_prob_flow.date_valid = '|| tablename ||'.date_valid)
              WHERE '|| tablename ||'.id_location = '|| location_id ||'
                AND '|| tablename ||'.date_product = '''|| product_date ||'''
                AND '|| tablename ||'.id_member = '|| count ||'';

    EXECUTE query INTO curr_value;

    EXECUTE 'UPDATE temp_table_icrm_prob_flow 
             SET value'|| count ||' = COALESCE('|| curr_value ||', -999)';

    count := count + 1;
  END LOOP;

  EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE temp_table_icrm_prob_flow DROP COLUMN date_valid';

  EXECUTE 'COPY temp_table_icrm_prob_flow TO '''||dest_file||''' DELIMITER '','' CSV';

  EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE temp_table_icrm_prob_flow';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Output:

```
NOTICE:  tablename: inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow
NOTICE:  location_id: 38
NOTICE:  product_date: 2015-02-05 12:00:00+00
NOTICE:  count: 1
ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inform_icrm_prob_flow_query(text,integer,text,integer,integer,integer,integer,text) line 38 at EXECUTE
```

If none of the variables I am passing in are null, and the only other thing referenced is a temp table that I know exists, what could be causing this error?

Note: when changing my query to:

```
query := 'SELECT value FROM '|| tablename ||' WHERE '|| tablename ||'.id_location = '|| location_id ||' AND '|| tablename ||'.date_product = '''|| product_date ||''' AND '|| tablename ||'.id_member = '|| count ||' AND temp_table_icrm_prob_flow.date_va    lid = '|| tablename ||'.date_valid';
```

I get the following error:

```
NOTICE:  tablename: inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow
NOTICE:  location_id: 38
NOTICE:  product_date: 2015-02-05 12:00:00+00
NOTICE:  count: 1
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "temp_table_icrm_prob_flow"
LINE 1: ..._data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow.id_member = 1 AND temp_table...
                                                         ^
QUERY:  SELECT value FROM inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow WHERE inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow.id_location = 38 AND inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow.date_product = '2015-02-05 12:00:00+00' AND inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow.id_member = 1 AND temp_table_icrm_prob_flow.date_valid = inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow.date_valid
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inform_icrm_prob_flow_query(text,integer,text,integer,integer,integer,integer,text) line 35 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: Check `curr_value` after `EXECUTE query INTO curr_value;`

Comment: curr_value is unsurprisingly null

Comment: So we are found your problem. Use `execute '...' into strict ...;` to ensure that the query returns the data.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Abelisto As per the docs: `If the STRICT option is given, an error is reported unless the query produces exactly one row`. You solve a symptom, not a problem.

Comment: Why do it the right way if there is a HORRIBLY WRONG way of doing it? You seem to want to export some data from some table using a filter over a specified time period. Why don't you tell us what you want and then maybe you will get an answer that is actually efficient. What you have here is verifiably inefficient in multiple ways.

Comment: @Patrick I not solved anything, I just pointed to the problem source. And when you edited the question you forget to edit the line numbers where errors occurred.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry for small offtopic. Your code is pretty unreadable (and SQL injecttion vulnerable). There are some techniques, that you can use:

1. Use clause `USING` of [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) statement for usual parameters.

   ```
   DO $$
   DECLARE
     tablename text := 'mytab';
     from_date date := CURRENT_DATE;
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(tablename) || ' VALUES($1)'
         USING from_date;
   END
   $$;
   ```

   This code will be safe (due using `quote_ident` function), little bit faster (due using binary value of *from_date* variable - removed multiple string<->date conversions and little bit more readable (because string expression is shorter).
2. Use function `format`. The building query string will be shorter and more readable (table aliases helps too):

   ```
   query := format('
   SELECT value
      FROM %I _dtn
           INNER JOIN temp_table_icrm_prob_flow t ON t.date_valid = _dtn.date_valid
     WHERE _dtn.id_location = $1
       AND _dtn.date_product = $2
       AND _dtd.id_member = $3'
                    , tablename);
    EXECUTE query INTO curr_value USING location_id, product_date, count;
   ```

Using variables named like important SQL keywords and identifier is wrong idea - names *count*, *values* are wrong.

The error message is clean - you are using the identifier `temp_table_icrm_prob_flow.date_valid`, but the table *temp_table_icrm_prob_flow* is not mentioned in query. The query missing JOIN part.